# Performance issue in retrieving multiple output of the same column with different values from a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

is there anyway to get the following results from query without joining the same table three times (or) without reading the same "wordlocation" table three times (or more if there are more words)? If there are three or more words, it takes about over a minute for the results to be returned.

Currently "wordlocation" table has three rows being ("bookid","wordid","location") and it currently has 917802 rows.

What I am trying to do is

1. retrieve the "bookid" that contains all the words specified in the query by "wordid".
2. sum word count of all words (from the query) from each book
3. minimum values of each word location, e.g. (min(w0.location), min (w1.location)

I have tried commenting out count(w0.wordid) and min(location) calculations to see whether they are affecting the performance but this is not the case. Joining the same table multiple time was the case.

[image]

(this is the same code as the above image)

```
select 
    w0.bookid, 
    count(w0.wordid) as wcount, 
    abs(min(w0.location) + min(w1.location) + min(w2.location)) as wordlocation, 
    (abs(min(w0.location) - min(w1.location)) + abs(min(w1.location) - min(w2.location))) as distance 
    from 
    wordlocation as w0 
    inner join 
    wordlocation as w1 on w0.bookid = w1.bookid 
    join 
    wordlocation as w2 on w1.bookid = w2.bookid 
    where 
    w0.wordid =3 
    and 
    w1.wordid =52 
    and 
    w2.wordid =42
    group by w0.bookid 
    order by wcount desc;
```

This is the result that I am looking for, and which I got from running the above query, but it takes too long if I specify more than 3 words, e.g. (w0 = 3, w1 = 52 , w2 = 42, w3 = 71)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
    SELECT bookid,
      ABS(L3+L52+L42) as wordlocation,
      ABS(L3-L52)+ABS(L52-L42) as distance
    FROM 
      (SELECT bookid, wordid, CASE WHEN wordid=3 THEN min(location) ELSE 0 END L3,
         CASE WHEN wordid=52 THEN min(location) ELSE 0 END L52,
         CASE WHEN wordid=42 THEN min(location) ELSE 0 END L42
      FROM wordlocation WL
      WHERE wordid in (3,52,42)
      GROUP BY bookid, wordid) T
    GROUP BY bookid
```

You may also need to create index on `wordid`

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. wordid was indexed.